# react: create dynamic component with state and hook?

Tags: reactjs

I've seen a lot of example that render component from JSON dynamically

like this one

```
// the demo link
https://codepen.io/hyyan/pen/NmxMqY
```

but the example above only renders some pre-defined components, most of them don't have UI logic

and I am wondering how to create **really** dynamic component with state or hook inside it ?

I am developing a page builder project, I want the user can drag and drop some basic components like text, image, or button, and be able to attatch some extra logic inside the component.

I've read some articles about React Element (don't be confused with Nike shoes =_=), and I am thinking is it possible to do this by construct react elements to make the component has dynamic states and dynamic effects

https://indepth.dev/inside-fiber-in-depth-overview-of-the-new-reconciliation-algorithm-in-react/

Comment: For that you pass logic using props may be?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh emmm... working on it, I am trying to build a UI that can define components' states & effects & JSX, so cool but so hard XoX

Comment: If you want i've started a project on github from your example https://github.com/snettah/react-dynamic-components with lazy loading for components and i don't use class component so it's ok for using some hooks inside

Comment: @SafiNettah cool, let me see see